# AVR SPI programming issue

Tags: microcontroller, avr, spi, avrdude, attiny

I'm trying to program an ATtiny13A with `avrdude`, using an Olimex AVR-ISP500 programmer, through the 6-pin ICSP connector. However, I can't get it to communicate with my MCU. The user guide tells to use `-cstk500v2`, here is the log with this option: https://ghostbin.com/paste/8yx35, and here is the log with `-cavrisp`: https://ghostbin.com/paste/2rpx6 (the command is `$ avrdude -cXXXXXXX -P/dev/ttyACM0 -pattiny13 -v -F`). The chip signature changes, but it always starts with 0x88. Here is how it's connected:
[image: MCU side]
[image: ICSP side]

What might I have done wrong?

**UPD:** rearranged the wires like that:

```
[Vcc]  [MISO]  
[MOSI] [SCK]  
[GND]  [RST]
```

It now measures the voltage correctly, but is still unable to communicate with the MCU.

**UPD2:**  uploaded the new log with wires rearranged.

**UPD3:** on each side, both red and black wires are connected to a power supply, red to Vcc, black to GND.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The programmer was too fast, `-B5` solved it.